# vbscript that enters SQL and prints selected values to .txt file

Tags: sql, vbscript, text-extraction

I'm trying to connect to a SQL server(localhost) and extract the following:

```
SELECT INVOICENO, SUPPLIERID, AMOUNT, DOCID
FROM ES_TRANS_HEADER
WHERE READYTOINVOICE = 1
```

I then need to get this information into a .txt file, seperated by commas

This is what I got so far:

```vbs
function accounting()
  Dim myStream, connection, myCommand, recValue
  Set myStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  connection.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI10;" & _
    "Data Source=localhost;" & _
    "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=SQLDatabase;" & _
    "User ID=;Password="
  myCommand.ActiveConnection=connection
  myCommand.CommandText="SELECT INVOICENO,SUPPLIERID, AMOUNT, DOCID FROM ES_TRANS_HEADER WHERE READYTOINVOICE = 1"
  SET recValue = myCommand.Execute()

  If Not recValue.EOF then
     MsgBox "INVOICENO = " & recValue(0) & vbcrlf & "SUPPLIERID=" & recValue(1) _
     & "AMOUNT="  &  recValue(2) & "DOCID=" & recValue(3)
  End If

  While Not recValue.EOF
    INVOICENO = recValue(0)
    SUPPLIERID = recValue(1)
    AMOUNT = recValue(2)
    DOCCID = recValue(3)
    recValue.MoveNext
  Wend
end function
```

Am I on the right track here, and if so what should I try to do next?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a syntax error in the `MsgBox` line (missing line continuation character). Other than that: is something not working as expected?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Ansgar Wiechers,

I've added the missing parentheses in the MsgBox, but was there anything else wrong with it? The problem is that I haven't been able to connect to the SQL yet, so I haven't been able to check if it retrieves the wanted data. I use windows authentication, and I don't require a password or username to connect, have I typed this correctly in the script by leaving it blank? Did you try the script yourself(with modifications obviously)? If so, did it run as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MsgBox` didn't have any parentheses missing. Remove them (and read Eric Lippert's most awesome [blog post on parentheses in VBScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx)). What's missing in that line is a line continuation character (`_`) at the end of the line. In VBScript you cannot wrap lines without that. Change this:

```vbs
MsgBox ("INVOICENO = " & recValue(0) & vbcrlf & "SUPPLIERID=" & recValue(1)
& "AMOUNT="  &  recValue(2) & "DOCID=" & recValue(3))
```

into this:

```vbs
MsgBox "INVOICENO = " & recValue(0) & vbcrlf & "SUPPLIERID=" & recValue(1) _
  & "AMOUNT="  &  recValue(2) & "DOCID=" & recValue(3)
```

or put the whole statement in a single line:

```vbs
MsgBox "INVOICENO = " & recValue(0) & vbcrlf & "SUPPLIERID=" & recValue(1) & "AMOUNT="  &  recValue(2) & "DOCID=" & recValue(3)
```

As for the database connection, your connection string seems odd. According to the information provided [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) that connection string is for connections to a mirrored database. Try this instead:

```vbs
db = "..."  'specify database name here
connection.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI10;" _
  & "Server=localhost;" _
  & "Database=" & db & ";" _
  & "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
```

If that doesn't help: check the value of the connection's [`State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property:

```vbs
WScript.Echo connection.State
```

Also, update your question with any error you're getting (error number, error message *and* line number).

Comment: I can now connect to the SQL, thanks a lot for the help ! Can't upvote you I'm afraid, since I need more "reputation" :(

Comment: I'm aware of that. No worries. Glad I could help.